# Set data object in vuejs using axios response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm making an API call and getting (an expected) error back. I can console log the error message but I can not seem to set a vuejs data variable with the response. What am I doing wrong?

```
        data: {
            ...
            ...
            errors: null
        },
        methods: {
            checkConnections: function (event) {
                axios.post('/checkconnections', {
                    //form data is passed here
                    ...
                    ...
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.response.data.error);
                    this.errors = error.response.data.error;
                });
            }
        }
```

The `console.log(error.response.data.error)` part works fine but the assignment `this.errors = error.response.data.error;` is not. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback - You could also read this post for additional clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The `this` value inside your catch handler isn't what you are expecting. The easiest way to fix that problem is to use an arrow function like `.catch(error => { this.errors = error.response.data.error; })`.

If your environment won't allow ES6 features, you can use [Function.bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) instead.